# Reformat timestamp in a pipe delimited file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a pipe delimited file with date time in this format `yyyymmddhhmmss` as below.

```
John|Doe|TEST|20210728120821|john@test.com
John|Davis|TEST|20210828120821|john@test.com
John|Smith|TEST|20210528120821|john@test.com
```

I am trying to convert the string in column 4 to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` like this

```
John|Doe|TEST|2021-07-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
John|Davis|TEST|2021-08-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
John|Smith|TEST|2021-05-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
```

As I am new to text processing in Linux, I searched and tried using `awk` like this

```
awk -F"|" '{OFS="|"; $4=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $4); print $0}'
```

But it didn't do the conversion as expected.

Comment: Please be careful when asking question and make sure your input accurately represents your real data. Otherwise, people will waste their time and yours giving solutions that don't work and then you edit the question and invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those "timestamps" aren't seconds since the epoch as `strftime()` operates on, they're just dates+times with no separators between years, months, etc. You just need a simple text manipulation, not use of time functions.

With GNU awk (which you're already using) for gensub():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$4=gensub(/(.{4})(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1-\\2-\\3 \\4:\\5:\\6",1,$4)} 1' file
John|Doe|TEST|2021-07-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
John|Davis|TEST|2021-08-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
John|Smith|TEST|2021-05-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$4=sprintf("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", substr($4,1,4), substr($4,5,2), substr($4,7,2), substr($4,9,2), substr($4,11,2), substr($4,13,2))} 1' file
John|Doe|TEST|2021-07-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
John|Davis|TEST|2021-08-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
John|Smith|TEST|2021-05-28 12:08:21|john@test.com
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use a `strftime`-like method, then you could consider [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html), which also provides the corresponding `strptime` ex.

```
$ mlr --nidx --fs '|' put -S '
    $4 = strftime(strptime($4,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  ' file
John|Doe|TEST|2021-07-28 12:08:21
John|Davis|TEST|2021-08-28 12:08:21
John|Smith|TEST|2021-05-28 12:08:21
```

Comment: This. The accepted answer’s claim that simple text manipulation is enough won’t hold when there are problems with the data—at least this approach can be expected to fail more obviously, rather than silently

Answer (score 6):

Assumption: The field to be changed is the only or first one that contains exactly 14 digits.

```
sed -E 's=\|([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\|=|\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6|='
```

Your attempt fails because `$4` would need to be the [*UNIX Epoch time* (time in seconds since 1970)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), as the [GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) documents.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a few `ex` answers, but I can't find the one about using `ex` for scripting. Anyway, here's a rather portable alternative that doesn't require installing tools like miller:

Put this in `script.vim`

```
global/|/normal! 03f|lct|^R=strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strptime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', @"))^M
wq
```

Then run `ex -S script.vim input-file`. (Changes are made in place; adjust the `wq` to `saveas file` followed by `quit!` if you don't like that, or maybe use `%print` and `quit!` to get something like "print to stdout".)

Make the `^R` and `^M` are literal control-R and control-M or carriage return characters (in vim, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>).